# Observation on normalized Ricci flow on two sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Note that two sphere with nonnegative curvature converges to canonical sphere along normalized Ricci flow. 
    So assume that if curvature is bounded below by $-\epsilon$ then the sphere meets a singularity or converges to a canonical sphere. Fix a metric $g$ with nonnegative curvature. Then is there $g_0$ such that

(1) curvature is not nonnegative

(2) if $g(t)$ is a solution converging to canonical sphere with $g(0)=g_0$ then $g(\epsilon_2)=g$ where $\epsilon_2>0$.

Is there such $g_0$ ?

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken but I thought the normalized  Ricci flow in 2d never has singularities.

Comment: @studiosus You are right.

Comment: Also, at the very least you need to assume that g is real analytic, so that the backward flow can exist.